# Is multibyte character set encoding different than utf8?

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, c++17

I have doing lots of reading on unicode and came to the conclusion that Unicode is a character set and utf8 is one of the possible encoding which happens to be multibyte encoding.
However, further readings confused me a bit when i was told that it's possible that my windows machine could have different locale settings than utf8.

1. If my application deals with utf8 then I will need to first convert from multibyte user input to wide chars and then to utf8.My first question is that why I need to do this as utf8 itself is a multibyte encoding. So why I need to do this round-trip?
2. My second question is that how can I get current locale in windows and Linux? Why this talk of locale is even existing? I mean why do we need to be even thinking about locale settings while writing a unicode aware c++ application?
3. My third question is that how the utf8 dealing inside the application different from the encoding in which the source files of the application are saved? Is there any relationship between the encoding which an application is dealing with (utf8 in my case) with the encoding with which the source code of the application is saved?
4. My fourth question is that what it actually means when we say an application is Unicode aware? Does it mean that it should deal with all possible Unicode encoding or a specific one? Given an application how can I find out which unicode encoding it supports?

Answer (score 1):

> Is multibyte character set encoding different than utf8?

UTF-8 is a multibyte character set, but other multi byte character sets exist.

> If my application deals with utf8 then I will need to first convert from multibyte user input to wide chars and then to utf8.My first question is that why I need to do this

You don't generally need to do this. If you have a case where this is necessary, then the reasons depend on that case.

> how can I get current locale in windows and Linux?

You can use the `std::setlocale` function. If you pass null as the second argument, it returns the locale for the category given as the first argument.

On POSIX systems, you can use the `nl_langinfo` function to get the character encoding of a given locale.

> Why this talk of locale is even existing?

Because different encodings, languages and conventions exist.

> I mean why do we need to be even thinking about locale settings while writing a unicode aware c++ application?

Firstly, there are other encodings besides unicode. Without locale, you couldn't know whether the current encoding is unicode or not.

Secondly, locale covers much more than just the encoding. Most importantly, it covers the language of the system. It also covers things such as what symbol is used as decimal separator.

Comment: So did you mean that setlocale with null argument will tell me what encoding is in use i.e the encoding of the input data? Will this be same as the codepage for windows?

Comment: @Test `So did you mean that setlocale with null argument will tell me what encoding is in use` Yes. `i.e the encoding of the input data?` If the input data is from a locale-aware function, then yes. If the input is from filesystem for example, then it can have a different encoding. `Will this be same as the codepage for windows?` To my understanding windows codepages are character encodings. If the current encoding is one of the codepages, then that's what it is. If it isn't, then it's something else.

Comment: thanks. How to find the encoding if the input is from windows console OR from a file on hard disk in windows?
Also, You didn't answer the question from point 4 in original question?

Comment: @Test `How to find the encoding if the input is from windows console` I don't know much about windows, but I would assume that it's whatever is the system encoding. `OR from a file on hard disk` You just have to know what encoding was used to create the file. There are techniques to guess the encoding, but any such trick will have a good chance of guessing incorrectly.